# Getting error - No Such Module 'SquarePointOfSaleSDK' on the import statement

Tags: square, square-connect

I have followed the cocoapods instructions faithfully: Podfile is:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios '9.0'

target 'SquareTesting' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SquareTesting

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firestore', :podspec => 'https://storage.googleapis.com/firebase-preview-drop/ios/firestore/0.7.0/Firestore.podspec.json'
  pod 'SquarePointOfSaleSDK'

end
```

I performed `pod update` and `pod install --repo-update` also, and the message: Using SquarePointOfSaleSDK (3.3.1) appeared in the verbiage.

The "SquarePointOfSaleSDK" pod appears in the list of installed pods in the file navigator.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried cleaning doing a clean build or clearing out your derived data directory? I assume you opened the workspace that Cocoapods created rather than the Xcode project?

Comment: Actually, I did! I removed the whole project directory, trashing all the files and started from scratch, following the github directions and got the same message. I will start over again to make sure.

Comment: Same issue here, I use pod to install SquarePointOfSaleSDK. And failed to import SquarePointOfSaleSDK module in my Objective-C project.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling one whole day, I gave up and use

```
#import <SquarePointOfSaleSDK.h>
```

instead of

```
@import SquarePointOfSaleSDK;
```

It works, however I want to know what is the best way to fix this issue.